# Estimating variances in orthogonal regression

Tags: regression, estimation, errors-in-variables, deming-regression, total-least-squares

In [orthogonal regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) it is assumed that both variables have noise.  I'm interested in the simplest possible case.  That is, I have a very large number of data points $(X_1,Y_1), ..., (X_n,Y_n)$.  I know that $Y = a X + b$ and that my $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are observations of an underlying $(X,Y)$ pair, with uncorrelated Gaussian noise.

The standard approaches for processing this data, to estimate $a$ and $b$ assume the standard deviation of the noise in $X$ and $Y$ is identical.  ([Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-an-orthogonal-regression-using-principal-components-analysis.html#zmw57dd0e3613) has one such presentation.)

My question: is there a way to estimate $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$?  My current approach examines the noise in $Y$ and $X$ after the orthogonal fit.  And see if they are commensurate.  Seems like a reasonable approach, but if there's an approach with a better foundation, I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models#Simple_linear_model) offers some considerations, even though it does not seem to answer your question specifically.

Comment: Try [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=786) pp. 785-787: "starting guess for $b$ ... finding the standard errors $\sigma_a \sigma_b$ is more complicated ..." (A question back, have you found a simple way to plot a say 90 % error region in XY ?)